# How to Pass an input function into another function without the input being asked twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

im trying to pass an input function with its variables into another function without having the input being asked twice, i in this instance would have already used the obtained the users input and would like to call the input rather than the input be asked again.

```
def Choice():
    ChoiceGame= input("Select whether you want to play game (a) or  (b)")
    return ChoiceGame
```

at this point i would then use this in another function to ask said question and obtain the input.

```
def GamePick(num_players = 2, num_cards2 = 4):

    ChoiceGame= Choice()
    if ChoiceGame== "a":
```

at this point i would like to use the past input to further develop the game without the question being asked for a second time. Any thoughts?

Comment: pass the value returned by `Choice()` (i.e. the variable you assign to its return value) as an argument to `GamePick()`.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could declare ChoiceGame as a global variable before you assign it a value:

```
def Choice():
    ChoiceGame= input("Select whether you want to play game (a) or  (b)")
    return ChoiceGame
  
def GamePick(num_players = 2, num_cards2 = 4):
    global ChoiceGame
    ChoiceGame = Choice()

GamePick()
```

Now that GamePick has run, ChoiceGame is available in *globals()*, outside the function I can run:

```
>>> ChoiceGame
Output : 'a'
```

---

Alternatively,
you could make it an attribute of a class, initialize it when you need and then access it from anywhere

```
class GamePick:
    def __init__(self, num_players = 2, num_cards2 = 4):
        
        self.num_players = num_players
        self.num_cards2 = num_cards2
        self.ChoiceGame= input("Select whether you want to play game (a) or  (b): ")
        
    
Game = GamePick()
```

Now you can get the ChoiceGame from anywhere like so:

```
>>> Game.ChoiceGame
Output : 'a'
```